# json data does not load after first time page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to read JSON data into JavaScript, but the data does not display on initial page load, only after the page is refreshed.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
            url:"http://192.168.0.105/stratagic-json/project_json.php",
            type:"GET",
            dataType:"json",
            beforeSend: function(){
            success:function(jsonData){
     var projctList = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
      projctList += ' <li><div class="proj-details-wrap"> <img src="images/project-img.jpg" /><div class="proj-badge">Upcoming Projects</div><div class="proj-name">'+ jsonData[i].name +'<span>'+ jsonData[i].location +'</span> </div><div class="proj-status">'+ jsonData[i].percentage +'% <span>completed</span> </div></div><div class="container proj-desc">'+ jsonData[i].description +' </div> </li>';
     }
          $("#projctLists").html(projctList);

     }
     }); 
});
```

```html
  <ul class="slides" id="projctLists">
        
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found one error, success is inside beforeSend, Corrected and shown below

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://192.168.0.105/stratagic-json/project_json.php",
            type:"GET",
            dataType:"json",
            beforeSend: function(){ },
                success:function(jsonData){
                    var projctList = '';

                    for (var i = 0; i  Upcoming Projects'+ jsonData[i].name +''+ jsonData[i].location +' '+ jsonData[i].percentage +'% completed '+ jsonData[i].description +'  ';
                    }
                    $("#projctLists").html(projctList);

                }
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove following line from code

```
 beforeSend: function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error near `beforeSend: function() {`
Use your code like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://192.168.0.105/stratagic-json/project_json.php",
            type:"GET",
            dataType:"json",
            beforeSend: function(){ },
                success:function(jsonData){
                    var projctList = '';

                   for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
  projctList += ' <li><div class="proj-details-wrap"> <img src="images/project-img.jpg" /><div class="proj-badge">Upcoming Projects</div><div class="proj-name">'+ jsonData[i].name +'<span>'+ jsonData[i].location +'</span> </div><div class="proj-status">'+ jsonData[i].percentage +'% <span>completed</span> </div></div><div class="container proj-desc">'+ jsonData[i].description +' </div> </li>';
 }
                    $("#projctLists").html(projctList);

                }
            });
    });
```